# How to use Miguel's Reachability classes?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm currently using Miguel's Reachability class to figure out if my device can connect a certain server. However, there are situations when checking takes very long. My call is:

```
Reachability.IsHostReachable ( sUrl )
```

And I'm trying to reach my server's URL.
But I'm not really interested in that. It would be enough to know if the device is currently registered in a WiFi network and if not, if it is connected through the carrier's GSM network. Wether it reach a host or not is secondary. As Reachability is not very well commented, I wonder if somebody knows what methods I would have to call?

EDIT:
It would already be enough if somebody explained the meaning of InternetConnectionStatus() and LocalWifiConnectionStatus() to me. The funny thing is: the first one always returns true even if I turn WiFi off.

Comment: So if you're on a wifi network but that network can't actually reach the internet, you don't care? You'd treat that the same way as a normal internet connection? Sounds a bit odd...

Comment: I assume that if the device is connected to WiFi, it will be able to reach the internet. This means I will try to download or whatever. To put it the other way: I want to figure out if the device is totally unconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use

```
Reachability.RemoteHostStatus() == NetworkStatus.NotReachable
```

to check for a connection. The `NetworkStatus` enumeration also includes `ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork` and `ReachableViaWiFiNetwork` which may come in handy for what you desire.

Comment: That's what I used to use but it really tries to reach a host (google.com is predefined) which in some situations seems to take a while. I would like to know if the device is currently registered in a WiFi network or a 3G network. If it can reach a host is secondary.

Comment: when you say "InternetConnectionStatus() always returns true..." how are you using `InternetConnectionStatus()`? I'm having a quick look at the code and it should be returning `NetworkStatus` not a bool? Do you mean it's always returning `NetworkStatus.ReachableViaWiFiNetwork` ?

Comment: Here are my calls: NetwaorkStatus eStatus = Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus(); This returns TRUE if the Wifi is currently able to reach the internet. However, if WiFi is off and I'm on 3G but 3G is currently not active, it returns NotReachable. This means, it does not try to fire up a 3G network connection in the first place and that is the issue I'm having. I would like to know 1) can I use Wifi? 2) can I use 3G?. I'm not interested in "can I reach a certain host".

Comment: The 3G is known to sometimes not wake up properly, you can try firing `MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.StartWWAN (Uri uri);` and then running the `Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus()` as a test to see whether that is the problem?